# Alternative to current Ruby on Rails testing methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I find that in order to thoroughly test a Rails application with Rspec I am required to write more test code than actual functional Ruby code. Call me crazy but this does not seems right. Is there a different/alternate approach (even one that is not as comprehensive as Rspec).

Comment: Perhaps you're over-testing? I like to start at the functional level and work my way down from there. What's your code:test ratio from `rake stats`?

Comment: What kind of tests are you writing at the moment? Can you give us an example?

Comment: you would typically have more test code than functional since you would need to simulate and test different conditions. i typically take a call on test density (how much of coverage I want to give to a particular piece of code). what exactly is your concern?

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing I guess you won't find any replacement.

But for integration testing, you could create scenarios within your browser thanks to Selenium. See: http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are many option available here are the few list

1. Rspec
2. Watir
3. Cucumber
4. factorygirl
5. capybara

   and many more